Built-in constants in Python not accessible via __builtins__ using dot syntax?
Reading Built-in Constants one can see that for example False is a built-in constant.
It is possible to retrieve it using:
>>> print(getattr(__builtins__, "False"))
False

But this fails:
>>> print(__builtins__.False)
File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(__builtins__.False)
                       ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I assume this fails because the word False gets recognized by the interpreter as the keyword / constant it refers to and so no attribute lookup takes place?
The documentation says about getattr:

Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar.

But for a reserved keyword (?) this does not hold?

I think __builtins__ is just for built-in functions, not variables.

"and so no attribute lookup takes place" You're not even reaching attribute lookup. False is tokenized as a keyword before the parser looks at it, so __builtins__.False is just invalid syntax.

@Barmar It does include constants too; see the docs. It also includes built-in exceptions and types, but those aren't mentioned in the docs for some reason.


I assume this fails because the word False gets recognized by the interpreter as the keyword [...] and so no attribute lookup takes place

Yes, that's correct. That's why you're getting a SyntaxError instead of a runtime error like AttributeError.
Other built-in constants are perfectly accessible, for example:
>>> __builtins__.NotImplemented
NotImplemented

More on keywords
See the docs on keywords:

The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers. They must be spelled exactly as written here:
False None True [...]

Compare that to the last sentence of the getattr() doc:

name need not be a Python identifier (see setattr()).

And at setattr():

An attribute whose name is not an identifier will not be accessible using the dot notation, but is accessible through getattr() etc.

That means you can also set/get attrs that aren't even remotely syntactically valid Python, for example:
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> setattr(f, '$', 'bar')
>>> getattr(f, '$')
'bar'
>>> f.$
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    f.$
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Thank you, perfect explanation. Answer accepted!

In attribute expressions, some_obj.some_attr the some_attr has to be a valid Python name (an identifier), which False is not, precisely because it is a keyword. Hence the syntax error (the code doesn't even compile).
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.iskeyword("False")
True

Compare the difference between:
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("sum")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (sum)
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("False")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 RETURN_CONST             0 (False)
>>> dis.dis("1337")
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 RETURN_CONST             0 (1337)


@nocomment they are only in the sense that they would be valid identifiers if not for the fact that they are reserved words.

@nocomment again, they are not valid identifiers precisely because they are keywords. That is why it raises a SyntaxError

I mean "not valid" as in "cannot be used as regular identifiers", which is the definition of a keyword not as in "otherwise wouldn't be a valid identifier"
